# SoapFault exception

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I'm using PHP Version 5.4.16

When I make a SOAP call, it gives me error:

```
SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in /var/www/html/VAS_sms/index.php:24
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/VAS_sms/index.php(24): SoapClient->__call('SendSMS', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/VAS_sms/index.php(24): SoapClient->SendSMS(Array)
#2 {main}
```

That's beside a Warning:

> Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'SoapClient' has no
>   effect in C:\wamp\www\VAS_sms\index.php on line 2

I lost my mind making it run..

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    use SoapClient;
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
    $wsdl_path = "https://smsvas.vlserv.com/KannelSending/service.asmx?WSDL";
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path, array('trace' => 1));

    $userName = "username";
    $Password = "password";
    $SMSText = "text";
    $SMSLang = "e";
    $SMSSender = "sender";
    $SMSReceiver = "01xxxxxxxxx";

    try {
        echo "<pre>\n";
        $result = $client->SendSMS(array(
                            "Username" => $userName,
                            "Password" => $Password,
                            "SMSText" => $SMSText,
                            "SMSLang" => $SMSLang,
                            "SMSSender" => $SMSSender,
                            "SMSReceiver" => $SMSReceiver));

            function objectToArray($d){
                if (is_object($d)){
                    $d = get_object_vars($d);
                }
                if (is_array($d)){
                    return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
                }
                else {return $d;}
            }

        $response_arr = objectToArray($result);
        echo "return_code= " . str_replace(";", "", $response_arr);
        echo "\n</pre>";
    }
    catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        echo $exception;      
    } 

?>
```

Any suggestions?

**side Q:** is there any file missing I should include instead of `use SoapClient;` ?!

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

in the documentation file:

```
<?php
use SoapClient;
$client = new SoapClient("https://smsvas.vlserv.com/KannelSending/service.asmx");
$userName = "username";
$Password = "password";
$SMSText = "text";
$SMSLang = "e";
$SMSSender = "sender";
$SMSReceiver = "01xxxxxxxxx";
$result = $client->SendSMS(array(
"Username" => $userName,
"Password" => $Password,
"SMSText" => $SMSText,
"SMSLang" => $SMSLang,
"SMSSender" => $SMSSender,
"SMSReceiver" => $SMSReceiver));
$response_arr = objectToArray($result);
echo "return_code= " . str_replace(";", "", $response_arr);
function objectToArray($d)
{
if (is_object($d))
{$d = get_object_vars($d);}
if (is_array($d))
{return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);}
else {return $d;}
}
?>
```

> Note:  We’re using PHP SoapClient to call the API Web Service, so you
>   need to enable the libxml PHP extension.  As its response is an
>   object (not string) so you need to convert it to an array by using
>   objectToArray function.

Comment: I dont think you should be doing that at all so try removing `use SoapClient;` As SoapClient is in the Global namespace.

Comment: thanks for your response, but Please see **Edit1** as I copied from the  documentation file.